# What processes on CentOS6/RHEL regulates user login but not password itself?

Tags: login, pam, consolekit

I was doing some maintenance via root account over ssh after several months of inattention. I shutdown, after startup I **can't log in to root account** at tty or via ssh. Fortunately, **sudo works** to perform root actions through my user account. There's **nothing special about the install**. Its out-of-the-box, so to speak. root uses local authentication.

I first tried changing the root password. The password change was successful, because I was also able to **authenticate against the root account** with: `authconfig --test`, which asks for root password outside of sudo/su.

**Reset permissions** and owner/groups with `rpm -a --setperms coreutils`

**PAM debug** on `pam_succeed_if.so`. Here is the last borked session using pam debug flag:

```
Jul 27 18:29:18 mrwizard sshd[2054]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 27 18:29:18 mrwizard sshd[2054]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 27 18:32:51 mrwizard login: pam_succeed_if(login:session): 'service' resolves to 'login'
Jul 27 18:32:51 mrwizard login: pam_succeed_if(login:session): requirement "service in crond" not met by user "root"
Jul 27 18:32:51 mrwizard login: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by LOGIN(uid=0)
Jul 27 18:32:51 mrwizard login: ROOT LOGIN ON tty1
Jul 27 18:32:52 mrwizard login: pam_succeed_if(login:session): 'service' resolves to 'login'
Jul 27 18:32:52 mrwizard login: pam_succeed_if(login:session): requirement "service in crond" not met by user "root"
Jul 27 18:32:52 mrwizard login: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user root
Jul 27 18:32:56 mrwizard login: pam_succeed_if(login:session): 'service' resolves to 'login'
Jul 27 18:32:56 mrwizard login: pam_succeed_if(login:session): requirement "service in crond" not met by user "root"
```

`requirement "service in crond"` [seems normal TMI](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=205067)

// As requested:

```
Jul 27 18:29:27 mrwizard crond[2271]: (CRON) STARTUP (1.4.4)
Jul 27 18:29:27 mrwizard crond[2271]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 34% if used.)
Jul 27 18:29:27 mrwizard crond[2271]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Jul 27 18:30:01 mrwizard CROND[2479]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 27 18:40:01 mrwizard CROND[5021]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 27 18:50:01 mrwizard CROND[7503]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 27 19:00:01 mrwizard CROND[10985]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 27 19:01:01 mrwizard CROND[11232]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 27 19:01:01 mrwizard run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[11232]: starting 0anacron
Jul 27 19:01:01 mrwizard run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[11241]: finished 0anacron
Jul 27 19:10:01 mrwizard CROND[13425]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 27 19:20:01 mrwizard CROND[16899]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 27 19:30:01 mrwizard CROND[19324]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 27 19:40:01 mrwizard CROND[21719]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 28 18:14:45 mrwizard crond[2317]: (CRON) STARTUP (1.4.4)
Jul 28 18:14:45 mrwizard crond[2317]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 45% if used.)
Jul 28 18:14:45 mrwizard crond[2317]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)

$ cat /etc/pam.d/crond 
# The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon
# No PAM authentication called, auth modules not needed
account    required   pam_access.so
account    include    password-auth
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
session    include    password-auth
auth       include    password-auth
```

Comment: Please post what you get with these commands:                                          "# tail -f /var/log/cron"
 and "# cat /etc/pam.d/crond"

Comment: Following the suggestion, I notice the `pam_access.so` file references `access.conf`. Curiously, my version is **completely** commented out. And, to _make my failure complete_ I don't have a backup to verify if it was _ever_ used. Which then reminds me of a warning in `pam.d/system-auth` suggesting that file is auto-generated. So, my question, if there was a hiccup from my remote administration using root, could other files in pam.d have [locked out root](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lock-unlock-set-number-of-login-attempts.html)?

Comment: I walked through PAM module pages [return values](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html) looking for `requirement...not met by user` without any success.